# PHP Shell_exec will affect environment variables?

Tags: php, shell, environment-variables

im using below command in PHP to trigger word application.

```
shell_exec(command);
```

Here my questions is

will it affect environment variables in system??. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: It certainly will not affect any environment anywhere "in the system", maybe except for a shell you start inside that command. no command changes any environment variable anywhere else. That is not possible. Such environment variables can be changed, but only for the current process. Then they get handed "down". That is all.